# how to splitProjects in one column in sql sever 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
WITH MYTABLE AS (
select Executive, count([Cat A]) AS [1-3], count([Cat B]) AS [4-6],count([Cat C]) AS [7-10],count([Cat D]) AS [11-15],count([Cat E]) AS [16+]
      from (
            select 
                  Executive,
                case  when [Next Follow Up Date] < GETDATE() and (DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) > 0 and DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) < 4)
                              then 'A'
                  end as [Cat A],
                  case  when [Next Follow Up Date] < GETDATE() and (DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) > 3 and DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) < 7)
                              then 'B'
                  end as [Cat B],
                  case when [Next Follow Up Date] < GETDATE() and (DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) > 6 and DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) < 11)
                              then 'C'
                  end as [Cat C],
                  case  when [Next Follow Up Date] < GETDATE() and (DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) > 10 and DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) < 16)
                              then 'D'
                  end as [Cat D],
                  case  when [Next Follow Up Date] < GETDATE() and (DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) > 15)
                              then 'E'
                  end as [Cat E]
                  from vw_FollowUps)
            as Table1

      group by Executive, [Cat A], [Cat B], [Cat C], [Cat D], [Cat E]
      )
  Select T1.Executive, SUM([1-3]) AS [1-3],SUM([4-6]) AS [4-6],SUM([7-10]) AS [7-10],SUM([11-15]) AS [11-15],SUM([16+]) AS [16+]
  from MYTABLE T1
  GROUP BY T1.Executive
```

---

```
i got output below

 Executive  1-3  4-6  7-10  11-15  16+

 kushali     1    2    0     1      2
 nirupama    0    1    1     3      1
```

---

but i need output below -here i want projects column and how we have to split projects in one column

```
Executive   Projects                 1-3  4-6  7-10  11-15  16+

kushali    swgruha,runi,nanuapa       1    2    0     1      2
nirupama   swgruha,runi,nanuapa       1    2    0     1      2
```

Comment: which table is your projects column in and how is that table related to vw_followUps ?

Comment: Do you want to split a column that is in the format 'x,y,z' into separate columns, or do you want to join separate entries for 'x','y', and 'z' into one comma-separated column?  Your question says "split", but your example suggests, "join".

Comment: i want x,y,z like that

Answer (score 0):

From your examples, it looks as if you are asking how to summarize a series of records in this form ...

```
 kushali      swgruha    1
 kushali      runi       1
 kushali      nanuapa    2
```

... to this form:

```
kushali      swgruha,runi,nanuapa      4
```

... so that you GROUP on the first column, aggregate the second column into a CSV (comma-separated variable) string, and perform a SUM on the third column.

This can be done, and there are a variety of ways.

Without knowing what table contains the strings you want to aggregate into a CSV string, I can't give you an exact SQL statement.  But you can find a step-by-step example [here](http://www.annlewkowicz.com/2011/01/doing-things-with-strings-sql-xml-and.html).  (Disclaimer:  that's my blog.)  You can do it using CTEs and some XML functions.